# Wrong legend with geom_label_repel and geom_label

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, geom-text

I am labelling a map with differents variables using geom_point, geom_label and geom_label_repel in a ggplot map.

All its ok but lamentably I can not add the legend for geom_label_repel (blue label), I tried with: scale_fill_manual, but dont solve my problem, example of my code and problem:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(maps)
library(ggrepel)

 county_df <- map_data('county') 
 ny <- subset(county_df, region=="new york")  
 ny <- ny[c(1:10, 30:40),]

ggplot(ny, aes(long, lat, group=group)) +  
    geom_polygon(colour='black', fill=NA)+
     geom_point(data = ny, aes(long, lat, size=group, color=order))+
     geom_label_repel(data = ny, aes(long, lat, label=subregion), 
                      fill = "#0033FF", box.padding = unit(.8, "lines"))+
     geom_label(data = ny, aes(long+.01, lat+.05, label=region, 
               fill="#FF3399"), colour = "White", fontface = "bold")+
     scale_fill_manual("Variable:", values=c("#FF3399", "#0033FF"), 
                  labels = c('Region', "Subregion"))
```

This command gave me this map, you can see the legend only for Pink label (Region) and not for the blue label (subregion):
[image: map1]

I tried using the command: show.legend = T, but lamentably this gave me a erroneous legend for the geom_point (group) and not show the legend for blue label(Subregion). The comand for this was:

```
ggplot(ny, aes(long, lat, group=group)) +  
    geom_polygon(colour='black', fill=NA)+
     geom_point(data = ny, aes(long, lat, size=group, color=order))+
     geom_label_repel(data = ny, aes(long, lat, label=subregion), 
                      fill = "#0033FF", box.padding = unit(.8, "lines"),
                      show.legend = T)+
     geom_label(data = ny, aes(long+.01, lat+.05, label=region, 
               fill="#FF3399"), colour = "White", fontface = "bold")+
     scale_fill_manual("Variable:", values=c("#FF3399", "#0033FF"), 
                  labels = c('Region', "Subregion"))
```

The map for this:

[image: map2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Looks like your `fill` aesthetic for subregions was outside its `aes()` so it technically wasn't 'mapped' and therefore did not showed up in the guide. The following fixes the problem I think:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(maps)
library(ggrepel)

county_df <- map_data('county') 
ny <- subset(county_df, region=="new york")  
ny <- ny[c(1:10, 30:40),]

ggplot(ny, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(colour = 'black', fill = NA) +
  geom_point(data = ny, aes(long, lat, size = group, color = order)) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = ny,
    aes(long, lat, label = subregion, fill = "#0033FF"),
    box.padding = unit(.8, "lines")
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = ny,
    aes(long + .01, lat + .05, label = region, fill = "#FF3399"),
    colour = "White",
    fontface = "bold"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(aesthetics = "fill",
    "Variable:",
    values = c("#FF3399", "#0033FF"),
    labels = c('Region', "Subregion")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! a little big detail!